# Empty file stored on Firebase with Python

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-storage, pyrebase

My goal is to generate certain files (txt/pdf/excel) on my Python server and subsequently push it to the Firebase Storage.

For the Firebase Storage integration I use the pyrebase package.

So far I have managed to generate the file locally and subsequently store it on the right path on the Firebase Storage database.

However, the files I store are always empty. What is the reason for this?

## 1. Generating the localFile

```
import os
def save_templocalfile(specs):


    # Random something
    localFileName = "test.txt"
    localFile     = open(localFileName,"w+")
    for i in range(1000):
        localFile.write("This is line %d\r\n" % (i+1))


    return {
            'localFileName':    localFileName,
            'localFile':        localFile
        }
```

## 2. Storing the localFile

```
# Required Libraries
import pyrebase
import time


# Firebase Setup & Admin Auth
config = {
  "apiKey":        "<PARAMETER>",
  "authDomain":    "<PARAMETER>",
  "databaseURL":   "<PARAMETER>",
  "projectId":     "<PARAMETER>",
  "storageBucket": "<PARAMETER>",
  "messagingSenderId": "<PARAMETER>"
}

firebase    = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
storage     = firebase.storage()


def fb_upload(localFile):


    # Define childref
    childRef      = "/test/test.txt"
    storage.child(childRef).put(localFile)


    # Get the file url
    fbResponse = storage.child(childRef).get_url(None)


    return fbResponse
```

Comment: May I see the output of the `request_object.json()` from `.put(localFile)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I opened my file with Write permissions only:

```
localFile = open(localFileName,"w+")
```

The solution was to close the write operation and opening it with Read permissions:

```
# close (Write)
localFile.close()

# Open (Read)
my_file       = open(localFileName, "rb")
my_bytes      = my_file.read()

# Store on FB
fbUploadObj   = storage.child(storageRef).put(my_bytes)
```