# pyrebase.storage() - Invalid HTTP method/URL pair

Tags: python, python-3.x, firebase, firebase-storage, pyrebase

I have a script where I tried to upload an image to the storage of firebse with `pyrebase` for which I use the`storage` function but it does not work and it throws the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Angel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyrebase\pyrebase.py", line 444, in raise_detailed_error
    request_object.raise_for_status()
  File "C:\Users\Angel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 940, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/gs://test-bc3ec.appspot.com//o?name=example.PNG

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Angel\Documents\respaldo\pyrebase_1..py", line 24, in <module>
    storage.child("/example.PNG").put("Captura.PNG")
  File "C:\Users\Angel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyrebase\pyrebase.py", line 406, in put
    raise_detailed_error(request_object)
  File "C:\Users\Angel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyrebase\pyrebase.py", line 448, in raise_detailed_error
    raise HTTPError(e, request_object.text)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: [Errno 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/gs://test-bc3ec.appspot.com//o?name=example.PNG] {
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid HTTP method/URL pair."
  }
}
[Finished in 2.4s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "C:\Users\Angel\Documents\respaldo\pyrebase_1..py"]
[dir: C:\Users\Angel\Documents\respaldo]
[path: C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Users\Angel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts\;C:\Users\Angel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\;C:\Users\Angel\Videos\flutter\bin;C:\Users\Angel\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin]
```

This is the code:

```
 import pyrebase

config = {
    "apiKey":"AIzaSyDphkVRuW39CyUbLmT5OkeZ2YmAUhwEUm4",
    "authDomain":"test-bc3ec",
    "databaseURL":"https://test-bc3ec.firebaseio.com/",
    "storageBucket":"gs://test-bc3ec.appspot.com/"
}
firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)

db = firebase.database()

uder = db.child("Nuevo").get()
print(uder.val())


#def stream_handler(message):
#   print(message['path'])
#   print(message['data'])


#myStream = db.child('Nuevo').stream(stream_handler)
storage = firebase.storage()
myfile = open("Captura.PNG","rb")
bytesm  = myfile.read()

fbupload = storage.child("/test/").put(bytesm)
```

Also try with `firebase_admin`

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials,db,storage

cred = credentials.Certificate("nuevo.json")
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred,{
    'databaseURL':'https://test-bc3ec.firebaseio.com/'
})

s = firebase_admin.storage()
s.child("imagenes/Captura.PNG").put("Captura.PNG")
```

**error in this code:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Angel\Documents\respaldo\firebase_ad.py", line 13, in <module>
    s = firebase_admin.storage()
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
[Finished in 0.8s]
```

but it does not work either

[image]

pyrebase **Second**

```
storage = firebase.storage()
myfile = open("Captura.PNG","rb")
bytesm  = myfile.read()

fbupload = storage.child("/test/Captura.png").put(bytesm)
```

Comment: Relevant [Empty file stored on Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53065238/7414759)

Comment: @stovfl,I've already tried that solution but it does not work

Comment: There is a [github issues/79](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase/issues/79), check your `pyrebase` version and read the **last 4 comments**.

Comment: @stovfl, 
Also try to remove the text gs // also change put by post and it did not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Question**: Invalid HTTP method/URL pair

1. `config["storageBucket"]`

   Using your `config`:

   ```
   "storageBucket":"gs://test-bc3ec.appspot.com/"
   ```

   > **Output**:
   >   *I get `Invalid HTTP method/URL pair.`*
   >
   > "error": {
   >   "code": 400,
   >   "message": "Invalid HTTP method/URL pair."
   >   }

   Changed to

   **Note: Removed the leading `gs://` and trailing `/`**.

   ```
   "storageBucket":"test-bc3ec.appspot.com"
   ```

   > **Output**:
   >   *I get `Permissin denied` instead of `Invalid HTTP method/URL pair`,
   >
   >   as i can't auth against `test-bc3ec`*
   >
   > "error": {
   >   "code": 403,
   >   "message": "Permission denied. Could not perform this operation"
   >   }
2. [Pyrebase#put](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase#put)

   > put
   >   **The put method takes the path to the local file and an optional user token**.
   >
   > ```
   > storage = firebase.storage()
   >
   > # as admin
   > storage.child("images/example.jpg").put("example2.jpg")
   >
   > # as user
   > storage.child("images/example.jpg").put("example2.jpg", user['idToken'])
   > ```
3. Your `storage`

   **Note: `"test"` without leading `/`.**

   ```
   storage = firebase.storage()

   local_file_path = "Captura.PNG"
   storage_file_path = "test/Captura.PNG"

   fbupload = storage.child(storage_file_path).put(local_file_path)
   ```

Please, report back Step3, as I can't verify this.

***Tested with Python:3.4.2 - Pyrebase:3.0.27***